# Can you express 1844 in a curious way?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Can you find integer values for $p$ and $q$ with $p,q\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ so that the following equation holds?

> $p^q - q^p = 1844$

Comment: None of the answers give any explanation beyond just the answer, which is trivial to find via computer (or paper and pencil, if you're dedicated). If that is the intended solution (i.e. there is no way to leverage particular properties of $1844$ for a solution), I don't think this is a puzzle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think

> <strike>p=1845 and q=1 works well</strike> **EDIT:** no longer applicable after new criteria introduced in the question
>  p=3 and q=7 too

Comment: 13 seconds faster than me. :)

Comment: Right answer 3 and 7

Comment: But what were the steps you used to get this?

Comment: @manshu The case of $p=1845$ and $q=1$ is trivial. After it was stated that we should look for $p$ and $q$ in the range of one-digit numbers, it was just simple brute force for $2\le{}p<q\le9$, where $p$ and $q$ have the same parity. Later by programming I checked for solutions where $\mathrm{max}(p,q)<10000$, but did not find anything else.

Answer (score 8):

A non trivial solution

> 3^7 - 7^3 = 1844

Answer (score 7):

One possible answer

> p = 1845 and q = 1

Because

> 1845^1 = 1845   1^1845 = 1   1845 - 1 = 1844

Comment: Sorry I forgot some description.

Comment: Well try I upvoted +1